# Function executed more times than expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a short Angular app:

```
angular.module('AppName', [])
.controller('TwoController', function($scope){
var oneArray = ['1','2'];
$scope.secondArray = [];
for (i in oneArray){
  $scope.secondArray.push({
    property: function(){
      console.log('1');
      return 'word';
    }
  })
}
});
```

In the view I have:

```
<div ng-app="AppName" ng-controller="TwoController">
<p ng-repeat='entry in secondArray'>{{entry.property()}}</p>
</div>
```

[The example on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/7f77un0v/)

It correctly displays the string `word` two times, but when I check the console, it shows function executed 4 times (via `console.log('1')`). Any idea on why?

Comment: Don't use your console inside push(). Use it after for() statement before .push() you will only get 2 time console value. doesn't matter which type of loop you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `for..in` loops on properties and Array have the property `length` too and another one that make it loop another time. IUf you want to see it just do `console.log(i)`

Either use a `angular.forEach` or the old `for(var i = 0; i < ...)`

EDIT : failed answer : The reason is because of angular.

He will go through the list twice : once at init and once at the end of his loop to check for changes

Comment: Ah my bad didn't see this is because of AngularJS, he will go trough your list twice : once at init, and a second time after he finish his digest loop, to check for changes.

Comment: @Walfrat to which list are you referring?

Comment: secondArray : because of the ng-repeat, the loop executed by ng-repeat will be executed twice : once in order to display the value. Once at the end of digest loop to check for changes.

Comment: @Walfrat Are you saying that the $scope is rebuilt at every iteration of ng-repeat?

Comment: No, 1st the ng-repeat create is hown scope where he'll store his data. This is the first execution of your functions, second he put a watch on it, watches are test at the end of angular loop, this is athe second execution of your functions

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the view just gets rendered twice, so i don't think you have a real problem...

Comment: How did you checked that?