# angularjs bind function call to span without triggering event

Tags: angularjs, function, label, ng-bind

I use ng-repeat to populate my table. One of the columns in the table should be dynamically populated again by a different function call.

Below is my code snippet.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">      
  <td><span ng-bind="item.name"></span></td>
  <td><span ng-bind="getItemDetails(item.id)"></span></td>
</tr>
```

I have array of items. I need to display those items in a table. Item name will be present in the item object, however, item details will be populated by another function call which needs item id.

On using **ng-bind** (like in the code above) I face 2 issues.

1. Multiple calls to function even if array has 1 items. Sometimes it goes on thereby freezing my browser and server out of memory issue
2. The item id doesn't get passed to function always. Sometimes it is undefined.

I am not sure if **ng-bind** is the right directive to be used. **ng-model** doesn't work though. Is there any other directive or other way to do it?

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the jsfiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/grubxaur/

If you check browser console, you can see the function is called twice. I guess it is called N no. of times where N is no. of columns in the table.

Comment: Is there a JSFiddle of your issue?

Comment: Functions in `ng-bind` expressions get called every digest cycle. We would need to see the code for the function to understand why it is not returning values consistently. Best guess: **Angular Expressions don't work well with asynchronous operations.** Don't do it.

Comment: @yuvraj, I have edited my question to include jsfiddle. If you check your browser console, you can see that the function is called twice.

Comment: I had something similar, with multiple function calls [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690747/function-executed-more-times-than-expected). Although the context somewhat differs, I think they have the same cause.

Comment: @neptune, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Maz seems that this is the way Angular working, so I can't see anything  to do other than some refactoring of your code. You may use a custom filter if you want view changes on a scope variable bind in the second td.

Comment: @neptune. Thank you. I have changed my implementation and it is working fine. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweaked my implementation a bit to get rid of this issue. Rather than calling a function within **ng-repeat**, I modified the **items** array within the controller using `angular.forEach` before **ng-repeat** is invoked.

Something like code below.

```
angular.forEach(self.items, function(item){
     item.details = $scope.getItemDetails(item.id);
});
```